Eclipse GMF not working after upgrade from eclipse 4.6.3 to 4.23
We have a RCP product based on Eclipse which we have upgraded from Eclipse 4.6.3 to 4.23.
We are using Eclipse GMF for activity diagram functionality. One of the class CreateElementAction.java class which extends org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.java and overriden run() method as follows:
 @Override
public void run() {
    Request req= new CreateUnspecifiedTypeRequest(getElementTypes(), getPreferenceHint());
    DiagramEditPart diagramEditPart = getDiagramEditPart();
    if(diagramEditPart.isEditModeEnabled()){
        Command cmd = getDiagramEditPart().getCommand(req);
        if(cmd.canExecute()){
            cmd.execute();
            if(cmd instanceof ICommandProxy){
                CommandResult results = ((ICommandProxy)cmd).getICommand().getCommandResult();
                System.out.println(results);
            }
        }
    }
    
}

The above code works perfectly fine until we upgraded Eclipse. With Eclipse 4.23, below line throws Null pointer exception.
 Command cmd = getDiagramEditPart().getCommand(req);

 java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.epf.diagram.core.actions.CreateElementAction.run(CreateElementAction.java:51)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:474)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:414)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4243)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1063)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1087)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1072)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:775)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$8(ActionContributionItem.java:1207)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4243)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1063)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4060)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3632)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
at org.eclipse.epf.rcp.ui.MainApplication.createWorkbenchAdvisor(MainApplication.java:116)
at org.eclipse.epf.rcp.ui.MainApplication.start(MainApplication.java:82)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1440)

Upon code debug, it is observed that the above code getCommand(req) is internally using Eclipse Graphical Modelling Framework and receiving null from below method call:
org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.editparts.GraphicalEditPart -> public Command getCommand(Request _request).
Because of this issue, no customised nodes can be added to diagram, looks like pallete is disabled. However, default ones like circle, rectangle, etc. are working fine.
Is it a bug or different way to achieve this functionality in Eclipse 4.32. Any pointers on how to resolve the issue would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Are you really going to update to Eclipse 4.23 which is more than two years and nine releases behind? Or to the current Eclipse version 4.32 as stated at the end of your question? If you upgrade to Eclipse 4.32 you should also upgrade to GMF 1.16.4 as both are part of the Eclipse IDE 2024-06 release. See also migration guide of Eclipse and GMF.
